# Mongodb query group result

Tags: mongodb

I need to pick <=4 employees who has the experience 3 to 9 and their sum of salary should be less than or equal to 200000 from following data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db3"),
    "name" : "Anderson Heidenreich",
    "experience" : 6,
    "expected_salary" : 36252
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db4"),
    "name" : "Dr. Collin Stanton IV",
    "experience" : 8,
    "expected_salary" : 56000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db5"),
    "name" : "Zita Von",
    "experience" : 2,
    "expected_salary" : 41792
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db6"),
    "name" : "Gregory Reilly",
    "experience" : 7,
    "expected_salary" : 77000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db7"),
    "name" : "Prof. Myles Hackett",
    "experience" : 3,
    "expected_salary" : 49133
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db8"),
    "name" : "Janelle Thiel",
    "experience" : 4,
    "expected_salary" : 78795
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db9"),
    "name" : "Dr. Elsie Lang",
    "experience" : 2,
    "expected_salary" : 99135
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9dba"),
    "name" : "Sean Braun",
    "experience" : 2,
    "expected_salary" : 63608
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9dbb"),
    "name" : "Murray Simonis",
    "experience" : 7,
    "expected_salary" : 66000
}
```

expected output like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db4"),
    "name" : "Dr. Collin Stanton IV",
    "experience" : 8,
    "expected_salary" : 56000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db6"),
    "name" : "Gregory Reilly",
    "experience" : 7,
    "expected_salary" : 7700
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9dbb"),
    "name" : "Murray Simonis",
    "experience" : 7,
    "expected_salary" : 66000
}
```

can you suggest me how to do with mongodb query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a simple find query with the experience ranges then sort the results by salary and limit the results to only 4.

```
db.stack.find( { "experience": {$gt: 3, $lt: 9} }).sort({"expected_salary" : -1 }).limit(4)
```

This will then output the following results:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db8"), "name" : "Janelle Thiel", "experience" : 4, "expected_salary" : 78795 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db6"), "name" : "Gregory Reilly", "experience" : 7, "expected_salary" : 77000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9dbb"), "name" : "Murray Simonis", "experience" : 7, "expected_salary" : 66000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("593a311650692f17327f9db4"), "name" : "Dr. Collin Stanton IV", "experience" : 8, "expected_salary" : 56000 }
```

Now on our client side we can just loop though the results until we have the expected value

We've used some mongodb query operators (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/)

`$gt:` - Greater than
`$lt:` - Less than

Comment: The question asks for the *sum* of `expected_salary` to be less than 200K. I guess with the limit on records you could just do it by getting four records and popping one until the sum requirement is satisifed.

Comment: In general you are asking for https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ but you cannot do conditionals on aggregations. So I stick with Kevin's idea for the first part of the problem and proposing and a solution in your result handling for the sum aspect.

Comment: Missed that on the question, instead of the `expected_salary` query on mine, `.sort({"expected_salary" : -1}).limit(4)` take the results and just sum it up on the application side to get the final results.

Comment: I do not think that sorting is what he whishes for... he just wants his employees in 200K slices.

Comment: I've updated the answer but little confused about the question now

Comment: @KevinSmith i need employee who's salary summation should be <= 200K and that employee list with sort experience by descending.